# Problems with building a MITM proxy with Netty that handles both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I am trying to learn how to use Netty to build a MITM proxy. My goal is for the proxy to handle both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port. For simplicity, the proxy will only respond with a hello-world message for any inbound message. I did a lot of study, but I am still having trouble to achieve my goal.

Below are relevant codes that I wrote.

```
// HTTP/HTTPS proxy service handler
public class InboundFrontHandler extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    private static final HttpResponse CONNECT_RESPONSE = new DefaultHttpResponse( HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
            new HttpResponseStatus( 200, "Connection established") );

    @Override
    protected void decode( ChannelHandlerContext context, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out ) {
        log.info("Decoding message.");
        // Will use the first five bytes to detect a protocol.
        if (in.readableBytes() < 5) {
            return;
        }

        log.info("Received message: {}", in.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        ChannelPipeline pipeline = context.pipeline();

        if (SslHandler.isEncrypted( in ) ) {
            log.info("message is encrypted.");
            if( pipeline.get( SSL_HANDLER ) == null ) {   // SSL_HANDLER: String
                log.info("no ssl handler available.");
                if( pipeline.get( HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER ) == null ) { // HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER: String
                    log.info("no http codec available");
                    pipeline.addLast(SSL_HANDLER, getSslHandler());
                    pipeline.addLast( HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER, new HttpServerCodec());
                    pipeline.addLast( DEFLATER_HANDLER, new HttpContentCompressor()); // DEFLATER_HANDLER: String
                } else {
                    log.info("http codec available");
                    pipeline.addBefore( HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER, SSL_HANDLER, getSslHandler());
                }
            }
        } else {
            log.info("message is not encrypted");
            if( pipeline.get( HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER ) == null ) {
                pipeline.addLast( HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER, new HttpServerCodec());
                pipeline.addLast( DEFLATER_HANDLER, new HttpContentCompressor());
            }
            if( isConnect( in ) ) {
                context.write( CONNECT_RESPONSE );
                log.info("responded CONNECT method with {}", CONNECT_RESPONSE);
                return;
            }
        }

        if( pipeline.get(HW_HANDLER) == null) {  // HW_HANDLER: String
            pipeline.addLast( HW_HANDLER, new HttpHandler());
        }
    }

    private boolean isConnect(ByteBuf in) {
        int magic1 = in.getUnsignedByte(in.readerIndex());
        int magic2 = in.getUnsignedByte(in.readerIndex() + 1);
        return magic1 == 'C' && magic2 == 'O';
    }

    private SslHandler getSslHandler() { // get a SslHandler with a self signed certificate in keystore
        SSLEngine engine = null;
        try {
            engine = SslContextFactory.createServerSslContext().createSSLEngine();
            engine.setUseClientMode(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new SslHandler(engine);
    }
}

// Dummy hello-world response generator
public class HttpHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger( HttpHandler.class );

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete( ChannelHandlerContext context ) {
        context.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead( ChannelHandlerContext context, Object message ) {
        if( message instanceof HttpRequest ) {
            HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) message;
            log.info(request.toString());

            HttpResponse response = helloWorldResponse();
            log.info( response.toString() );

            context.write( response );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

    private HttpResponse helloWorldResponse() {
        byte[] content = "Hello, World".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                HttpResponseStatus.OK, Unpooled.wrappedBuffer( content ));
        response.headers().set( HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
        response.headers().set( HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());

        response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);

        return response;
    }
}

// Server bootstrap
public class HttpServer {
    final int port = 1119;
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024);
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast(new InboundFrontHandler());
                        }
                    });

            Channel ch = b.bind(port).sync().channel();
            ch.closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran the proxy, and typed url `https://www.google.com` in Chrome, I got the following logs:

```
2014-10-19/22:01:25.139 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector.debug(): -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel: simple
    2014-10-19/22:01:25.147 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  c.t.n.p.InboundFrontHandler.decode(): Decoding message.
    2014-10-19/22:01:25.149 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  c.t.n.p.InboundFrontHandler.decode(): Received message: CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.google.com
    Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36


    2014-10-19/22:01:25.151 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  c.t.n.p.InboundFrontHandler.decode(): message is not encrypted
    2014-10-19/22:01:25.168 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG i.n.u.i.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator.debug(): Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestMatcher
    2014-10-19/22:01:25.169 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG i.n.u.i.JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator.debug(): Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectMatcher
    2014-10-19/22:01:25.171 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  c.t.n.p.InboundFrontHandler.decode(): responded CONNECT method with DefaultHttpResponse(decodeResult: success)
    HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
    2014-10-19/22:01:55.129 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  c.t.n.p.InboundFrontHandler.decode(): Decoding message.
    2014-10-19/22:01:55.129 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  c.t.n.p.InboundFrontHandler.decode(): Received message: CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.google.com
    Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36


    2014-10-19/22:01:55.129 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  c.t.n.p.InboundFrontHandler.decode(): message is not encrypted
    2014-10-19/22:01:55.134 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] WARN  i.n.c.DefaultChannelPipeline.warn(): An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
    io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate handler name: deflater
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:258) ~[netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelInactiveNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:46) ~[netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelInactive(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:77) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:299) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:827) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$5.run(AbstractChannel.java:544) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:318) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:353) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:794) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_72]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate handler name: deflater
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.checkDuplicateName(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:949) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:141) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:130) [netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        at com.tao.netty.proxy.InboundFrontHandler.decode(InboundFrontHandler.java:66) ~[main/:na]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:227) ~[netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha1.jar:5.0.0.Alpha1]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
```

There are a few things that I don't understand. First, as you can see from the logs, the browser retried the `CONNECT` request, indicating that it didn't treat the `CONNECT_RESPONSE` that the proxy sent back as a success for its last CONNECT request. Second, the code gave this exception message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate handler name: deflater
```

which was thrown from the following block:

```
        if( pipeline.get( HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER ) == null ) {
            pipeline.addLast( HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER, new HttpServerCodec());
            pipeline.addLast( DEFLATER_HANDLER, new HttpContentCompressor());  // <<< throws duplicate name exception after second CONNECT request
        }
```

It looks like `HTTP_CODEC_HANDLER` somehow become null but `DEFLATER_HANDLER` doesn't upon second CONNECT request, which is very confusing to me.

Third, while Chrome was retrying, its address bar had this string: `data:,`. It looks to me that Chrome is expecting some data from the response to the CONNECT request. Why?

I know this post is a lot to take. So, thank you very much for reading.

**update**
Below is a snapshot of the `data:,` thing from Chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you are writing into the pipeline with other handlers ahead of it. So if you add this piece of code in the `InboundFrontHandler`

```
log.info(context.pipeline().toMap());
context.writeAndFlush(CONNECT_RESPONSE).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
               log.info("WriteandFlush : " + future.isSuccess());
        }
});

the output would be 
INFO  test.InboundFrontHandler  - {InboundFrontHandler#0=test.InboundFrontHandler@1f060469, HttpRequestDecoder#0=io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder@1c3c34f6, HttpResponseEncoder#0=io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseEncoder@7333cf2a, DEFLATER_HANDLER=io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentCompressor@3d7fa45b}
INFO  test.InboundFrontHandler  - WriteandFlush : false
```

I suggest reading up on the examples : https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example

cos there are quite some mistakes regarding pipelines and how handlers are used and how writes are done. For example without flush the data wont be transferred.

Chrome sent another Connect request cos it did not receive the http 200 response. Another suggestion use `curl` to understand exactly what data is being sent across and received makes debugging a lot easier
Sample : 
`curl -x 127.0.0.1:1119 "https://www.google.com/" --trace -`

Comment: _@jknair: I actually solved the problem myself. But you are absolutely right, that I should not put any handlers ahead of the SSL handler. In a nutshell, what should happen is that the pipeline should initially have http handler. Upon receiving a CONNECT request, respond a 200 and then add the SSL handler before the http handler.