# How to handle both HTTP and RAW TCP/IP requests with KTor on one port

Tags: http-proxy, ktor

I'm trying to write a custom proxy with HTTPS support.
It means that I need to react to HTTP `CONNECT` command, then open TCP/IP connection to desired server and lets browser use it.

I can open RAW socket as described here
https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html#server_send
But I don't want then manually handle HTTP decoding.

I want to detect if it is HTTP or not and then use embedded HTTP parsing.
I currently don't need to do MITM, so I don't need to decode the incoming SSL stream.
But this is also possible in the future.

Something like
https://github.com/ravindraranwala/NettyReverseProxy/blob/master/NettyRPDemo/src/main/java/org/wso2/netty/SecureProxyInitializer.java#L64
or
[Problems with building a MITM proxy with Netty that handles both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459258/problems-with-building-a-mitm-proxy-with-netty-that-handles-both-http-and-https)

Comment: Unfortunately, Ktor doesn't support handling both HTTP and TCP/IP messages out-of-the-box. You can use Ktor's helper functions to decode and encode HTTP messages.

Comment: Do you know for which helper functions I should look up, please?

Comment: The `parseRequest` function to parse an HTTP request https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/815f247050cd83e39dfd0a7454e795b206907977/ktor-http/ktor-http-cio/common/src/io/ktor/http/cio/HttpParser.kt#L22 and the `RequestResponseBuilder` class to produce a response https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/815f247050cd83e39dfd0a7454e795b206907977/ktor-http/ktor-http-cio/jvm/src/io/ktor/http/cio/RequestResponseBuilder.kt#L14